# Google App Engine 1.3.1 <admin-console> Issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven-gae-plugin

I attempted to add an `<admin-console>` section to my appengine-web.xml and I got the exception below. The `<admin-console>` element is a valid element according to the appengine-web.xsd. It's also documented in the app engine [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html). Any ideas as to what is wrong?

```
<admin-console>
    <page name="My Admin" url="/app/admin" />
</admin-console>

Feb 14, 2010 12:40:09 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
SEVERE: Received exception processing C:/development/taylor/myapp/target/myapp-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Unrecognized element <admin-console>
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processSecondLevelNode(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:99)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:46)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:94)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:61)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.<init>(Application.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.readApplication(Application.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:107)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:58)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:54)
    at net.kindleit.gae.EngineGoalBase.runAppCfg(EngineGoalBase.java:140)
    at net.kindleit.gae.DeployGoal.execute(DeployGoal.java:38)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:579)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegmentForProject(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute_aroundBody0(DefaultMaven.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute_aroundBody1$advice(DefaultMaven.java:304)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:1)
    at org.apache.maven.embedder.MavenEmbedder.execute_aroundBody2(MavenEmbedder.java:904)
    at org.apache.maven.embedder.MavenEmbedder.execute_aroundBody3$advice(MavenEmbedder.java:304)
    at org.apache.maven.embedder.MavenEmbedder.execute(MavenEmbedder.java:1)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:408)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:351)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the maven-gae-plugin is still using the 1.3.0 SDK. Please see issues [39](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/issues/detail?id=39) and [41](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/issues/detail?id=41). The current 0.5.3 release does not contain the entire fix, but I have mentioned in the referenced issues what is needed in terms of updates to the 0.5.4-SNAPSHOT in order to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you might not be running 1.3.1, are you sure that you've installed the 1.3.1 sdk, and updated all of your variables and path-like references.

Comment: Yes, I'm referencing the 1.3.1 JAR's in my POM. However, now my suspicion is that the maven-gae-plugin is not using the 1.3.1 SDK. I looked at their source and they are using 1.3.0. Is the <admin-console> element new to 1.3.1?

Comment: Looked in the release notes and it looks like it is a new 1.3.1 feature. I bet the maven-gae-plugin is the problem then.

Comment: My problem now is that the custom admin page doesn't show up as a link in the sidebar. Have you ever gotten this to work?